# Assigning python dictionary's nested value without mentioning the immediate key

Tags: python

I have dozens of lines to update values in nested dictionary like this:

```py
dictionary["parent-key"]["child-key"] = [whatever]
```

And that goes with different `parent-key` for each lines, but it always has the same `child-key`s.
Also, the `[whatever]` part is written in unique manner for each lines, so the simple recursion isn't the option here. (Although one might suggest to make a separate lists of value to be assigned, and assign them to each dictionary entry later on.)

Is there a way do the same but in even shorter manner to avoid duplicated part of the code?

I'd be happy if it could be written something like this:

```py
update_child_val("parent-key") = [whatever]
```

---

By the way, that `[whatever]` part that I'm assigning will be a long and complicated code, therefore I don't wish to use function such as this:

```py
def update_child_val(parent_key, child_val):
  dictionary[parent_key]["child-key"] = child_val

update_child_val("parent-key", [whatever])
```

---

Specific Use Case:

I'm making ETL to convert database's table into CSV, and this is the part of the process. I wrote some bits of example below.

```py
single_item_template = {
  # Unique values will be assigned in place of `None`later
  "name": {
    "id": "name",
    "name": "Product Name",
    "val": None
  },
  "price": {
    "id": "price",
    "name": "Product Price (pre-tax)",
    "val": None
  },
  "tax": {
    "id": "tax",
    "name": "Sales Tax",
    "val": 10
  },
  "another column id": {
    "id": "another column id",
    "name": "another 'name' for this column",
    "val": "another 'val' for this column"
  },
  ..
}
```

And I have a separate area to assign values to the copy of the dictionary `single_item_template` for the each row of source database table.

```py
for table_row in table:
  item = Item(table_row)
```

`Item` class here will return the copy of dictionary `single_item_template` with updated values assigned for `item[column][val]`. And each of `val`s will involve unique process for changing values in setter function within the given class such as

```py
self._item["name"]["val"] = table_row["prod_name"].replace('_', ' ')
self._item["price"]["val"] = int(table_row["price_0"].replace(',', ''))
..
```

etcetera, etcetera.

In above example, `self._item` can be shortened easily by assigning it to variable, but I was wondering if I could also save the last five character `["val"]`.

(..or putting the last logic part as a string and `eval` later, which I really really do not want to do.)

(So basically all I'm saying here is that I'm lazy typing out `["val"]`, but I don't bother doing it either. Although I was still interested if there's such thing while I'm not even sure such thing exists in programming in general..)

Comment: You can use recursion and whenevr you reach a point when key is `"child-key"`. You assign `[whatever]` to it.

Comment: @Goion Each `[whatever]` is completely different, so recursion doesn't work in my case. Sorry, I would update to clarify on that!

Comment: Do you have a list of whatever's? where does it come from and how is it linked to the dictionary. the question is still not clear.

Comment: Why not just assign 'child-key' to a variable and use that in all the assignments? Low tech but easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: @Goion I added a little bit of an example there. It's part of ETL script's class.

Comment: @PaulRooney I really don't mind basic low-tech approach (as I'm indeed going for easy maintenance)! Would it be like assign each to an intermediate variable and then assign to dictionary later? (Because I'd love it if it could skip the intermediary part to avoid updating multiple parts upon maintenance.)

Comment: I mean just like `childkey='child-key'` then `dictionary["parent-key"][childkey]=whatever` for each assignment.

Comment: @PaulRooney Right, that's what I thought. Although that is an answer to my question, that's also not exactly what I was personally looking for (as that is a tad bit less maintainable in my opinion). (Maybe post as an answer if you don't bother?) Thanks for checking though. I had a strong feeling that the other option will be some crazy thing involving eval and stuff, so I just wanted to check on that.

Comment: There may be other options using stuff like a dict to map parent keys to assigned values or descriptors or other advanced stuff. I agree this method can be verbose and a bit ugly but at least doesnt give an a future reader any surprises. Also consider that your initial approach might be whats limiting you. It might be better to generate the csv completely in one pass.

Comment: @PaulRooney That totally makes sense, and I agree with the latter advice too. I spent hours questioning if my approach is as simple as it could be, but this involves a bit of edge case header is named in non-ASCII characters, so I just kinda went with this while continuously feeling like I'm doing things in weird ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't get away from doing the work, you can abstract it away in a couple of different ways.

Let's say you have a mapping of parent IDs to intended value:

```
values = {
    'name': None,
    'price': None,
    'tax': 10,
    '[another column id]': "[another 'val' for this column]"
}
```

Setting all of these at once is only two lines of code:

```
for parent, val in values.items():
    dictionary[parent]['val'] = val
```

Unfortunately there isn't an easy or legible way to transform this into a dict comprehension. You can easily put this into a utility function that will turn it into a one-line call:

```
def set_children(d, parents, values, child='val'):
    for parent, values in zip(parents, values):
        d[parent][child] = value

set_children(dictionary, values.keys(), values.values())
```

In this case, your `values` mapping will encode the transformations you want to perform:

```
values = {
    'name': table_row["prod_name"].replace('_', ' '),
    'price': int(table_row["price_0"].replace(',', '')),
    ...
}
```

Comment: Whoa this is it!! I totally don't mind extra work like this, and the fact that I only have to mention the parent key and child key once (on assignment side) in the whole code is super duper lovely. (Although I admit that this would be a bit of overwork for my specific use case, this was a great education for me!) Thanks a lot a lot!